# Can Oracle allow Permanent Alias for a table?

Tags: oracle, table-alias

I was given an oracle dump file for an existing system. The dump file contained the table PARTS but when I look on the queries being done by the code. It uses mostly **M_PARTS** and just on one occasion, it uses **PARTS**. Does oracle allow multiple name on a table?

Note that I am not talking about the alias feature. ie.

```
Select M_PARTS.*
from PARTS M_PARTS
```

I want to know if there is a setting to make permanent alias in oracle. Where I just create a table **PARTS** and I can refer to it as either **PARTS** or **M_PARTS** in my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a synonym was a solution, I found the actual script to build the database and it uses a materialized view  instead of a synonym.

```
create materialized view M_Parts            
tablespace USERS
refresh fast
as select * from Parts
```

Comment: Yeah. I do not know why the original designer of the system. They created refresh groups for several materialized view and always refresh the group when the application restarts. Probably for performance improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Kind of, as you can create synonyms:

```
CREATE SYNONYM PARTS FOR THE_SCHEMA.M_PARTS;
```

It is weird however, that the dump file would be inconsistent that way. Are you sure it is the same table? How was the file created?

Comment: I think the guy that created the dump file only added all tables and table values. All the other objects are gone, VIEWS, REFRESH OBJECTS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes using [synonyms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm).